# No empty constructor: android class

Tags: java, android, constructor

My problem is, I am transferring two arrays between activities. with an return from the one to another Activity. There I am getting these two Activities by the constructor( I think ). Is this correct? Why I am getting the error: no empty constructor?

Here is my class where the Activites are coming from:

```
public PlanOutputActivity fetchallRoutes(String startStop, String endStop, String time) {
.
.
.
return new PlanOutputActivity(convertArray(),routenArray);
```

Here is my Activity where i wanna get these two Arrays:

```
public class PlanOutputActivity extends Activity {

    Intent intent;
    Object[][] routenArray;
    String[][] itemsArray;
    DatabaseHelperActivity mdbH;
    public int RESULT_OK = 123;
    public int REQUEST_OK = 456;

    public PlanOutputActivity(String[][] itemsArray, String[][] routenArray){
        setContentView(R.layout.planoutputlayout);
        this.routenArray = routenArray;
        this.itemsArray = itemsArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }
     public void getRoute() {

        intent = getIntent();
        mdbH = new DatabaseHelperActivity(this);
        mdbH.fetchallRoutes(intent.getStringExtra("StartHaltestelle"),intent.getStringExtra("ZielHaltestelle"),intent.getStringExtra("Zeit"));
      ListView lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListOutput);
        ArrayAdapter<DefineRouteActivity> adapter = new RouteAdapterActivity(this, route);
        lvList.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int gKennung = view.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailOutputActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Kennung",gKennung);
                intent.putExtra("routenArray",routenArray);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an instance of an Android `Activity` using `new` - it simply doesn't work.

The only ways to create an `Activity` are either when it is launched from the Apps launcher or if you call `startActivity(...)` (or one of the other methods such as `startActivityForResult(...)` etc).

Because of that you shouldn't ever create constructors for an `Activity` and you should never create `public static` fields or methods with the intention of accessing data or calling methods in an `Activity` from any other application class.

If you want to pass data from one `Activity` to another do it using the extras in an `Intent` or simply persist the data in `SharedPreferences` or a database. Alternatively create a 'helper' class to hold the data - using the Singleton pattern is quite common for this.

Comment: is it possible to add an String[][] array to an intent and get this array after all in the second array?